# SSRS Document Map is gone after exporting report with cached reports

Tags: reporting-services

We are using Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 15.0.1102.932 and Microsoft Power BI Report Server Version 15.0.1108.153.

Some of our reports have a Document Map.  When we export to Excel we don't want the Document Map.  In the DocumentMapLabel we have logic like this:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML",Nothing,Fields!PAGR_ID.Value)
```

This works great.  However, we have found an issue when the Caching is set to use a cache that expires in X minutes or always run from a history snapshot (option 2 or 3).  After you export to Excel then run the report again for the same parameters, the document map is gone.

It appears when you export, the server fetches the data again so it can render it in the desired output format and creates a new record in the SnapshotData table in ReportServerTempDB.  I queried that table before running a report for the first time.  Ran the report, queried again and saw a new SnapshotData record, as expected.  I ran the report several times and noticed the table field TransientRefcount was increasing with each run.  Nice to know we can look at that and see how many times a cache has been accessed.  I then exported to Excel, queried the table and noticed a new record was created.  When I ran the report again with the same parameters I saw that new records TransientRefcount increase instead of the previous SnapshotData record.

Since our report turns off the document map when exporting to Excel, this new SnapshotData record doesn't have the document map in it.  Now when you run the report again with the same parameters, the document map is gone, because the server is grabbing the most recent cached data.

Has anyone encountered this and found a way to fix it?  A different way to turn off the document map?

I tried creating two tables, one with the document map and one without where the visibility of the table with the document map was set to hide if the RenderFormat is Excel and the other table hides when it's NOT Excel.  But that didn't work, the cached version only displays the version without the document map.  Which makes sense since the most recent cached version doesn't have a document map and it can't turn something on that isn't there.

One thought I had was to set the Globals!RenderFormat.Name to "RDL" when the report first runs before any parameters are entered, but I can't figure out how to do that.  Maybe with some code?  I've not used code in a report before so don't know how to do that.

Any thoughts?  Thanks very much!

Comment: I don't have an answer as such, but you might consider having two versions of the report, one with no docmap for Excel export only. From the current report, add a textbox with an action to "go to URL" and build the URL in the expression so it calls the Excel version directly with the correct render format, this way the user would click the link and immediately get the Excel download without having to open the Excel version interactively first

Comment: On a Microsoft forum I was told by a MS employee that my theory is correct and by design. I was actually playing with the exact idea you mentioned. It works great, though it means we have to create linked reports for every report they could possibly export to Excel. :( Oh well, at least it's a solution. Thanks!